# Efficient Search for Two Values in Large PostgreSQL Table

Tags: postgresql, where-in

I have a large PostgreSQL table (350mm rows) which looks like the below structure (data types are: date, text, text, text). It is called for this example test_table:

```
   date      symbol     value   created_time
1996-02-12   symbol1    101.2   1515614976548
1996-02-13   symbol1    100.5   1515614976548
1996-02-16   symbol1    102     1515614976548
1996-02-12   symbol2    200     1515614976700
1996-02-13   symbol2    202     1515614976700
1996-02-16   symbol2    205     1515614976700
```

My goal when querying this table is to retrieve all 4 of these columns matching a specific symbol and created_time (so looking up using two values for each row).

My current query is below:

```
select * 
from "ts.global.bbg__price.none"
where (symbol, created_time) in (values ('symbol1','1515614976548'), ('symbol2','1515614976700'), ('symbol3','1515614976750'))
```

And currently, I have an index on the table with symbol and created time.

Here is the query planner:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.64..1323.84 rows=1300 width=33) (actual time=5.394..233.821 rows=14499 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=79 read=132
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.07..0.11 rows=4 width=64) (actual time=0.009..0.011 rows=4 loops=1)
        Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1, "*VALUES*".column2
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=4 width=64) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using "ts.global.bbg__price.none_idx" on "ts.global.bbg__price.none"  (cost=0.57..330.12 rows=81 width=33) (actual time=5.772..57.933 rows=3625 loops=4)
        Index Cond: ((symbol = "*VALUES*".column1) AND (created_time = "*VALUES*".column2))
        Buffers: shared hit=79 read=132
Planning time: 8.095 ms
Execution time: 234.521 ms
```

As I am quite new to using PostgreSQL I wanted to see if 1) there is a better way to query/use indexes to retrieve data in this manner (I will be often retreiving around 4,000 rows per symbol and anywhere between 10 and 200 symbols at a time) and 2) given that my tables will grow quite large because I am storing everything in an immutable fashion (there are duplicate values and dates) is this not a good use of postgres.

Thank you for any advice in advance.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't really need the `values` clause for the `IN` condition: `where (symbol, created_time) in ( ('symbol1','1515614976548'),  ... )` will do just fine. You might want to try a `join` on that `values` clause though, maybe that improves the performance `from ... join (values (...)) as t(s,c) where symbol = t.s and created_time = t.c`

Comment: Thank you, I just updated it. I think it formatted pretty well but if there is a better way to format execution plans I would love to learn how.

Comment: Formatting is fine ;) However, 230ms does not seem slow to me. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: I really didnt have much frame of reference, wanted to see if I was missing something or doing something potentially harmful as this table grows. Its good to hear that is fast. I will try the join as you suggested. Otherwise sounds like it might not really be a problem at all.